# Stopping a jQuery function if = true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a website for my new brand and as my first in-depth encounter with jQuery, I've found some issues relating to the state of a div. The if statements in the code check if the text of #homebutton is equal to either 'blog' or 'home', and then issue a different scrollTop() command for each one. The problem is that I need to cease the jQuery function - say for instance if blog is the text, I don't want it to run the function (which involves changing the text of #homebutton to home) AND THEN running the if text = home if statement as well (because the text has changed). I need a way to either stop the jQuery function after it does one of the scrollTop() commands or I would like someone to show me how to craft an IF statement that can eliminate this problem.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
        });

        $("#askbutton").click(function() { 
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
            $("#askpage").toggle("slow");
            $("#tumblrcontent").toggle("slow");
            $("#homebutton").text("HOME");
          });


        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var targetDiv = $('#homebutton');
            var matchHeight = $('#tumblrcontent').position().top;
            if($(document.body).scrollTop() >= matchHeight) {
                // this is where you're css amendments would be done
                if (targetDiv.text('BLOG')) {  targetDiv.text('HOME'); }
            } else {
                if (targetDiv.text('HOME')) { targetDiv.text('BLOG'); }
            }
        });

        $("#homebutton").click(function() { 
        if ($(this).text("HOME") && $("#tumblrcontent").css('display', 'none')){
                $("#askpage").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#tumblrcontent").fadeIn("slow");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow"); 
                $(this).text("BLOG");
                //if tumblrcontent is not shown and text says home, this means that #askpage will be showing.
        }

        if ($(this).text("HOME") && $("#askpage").css('display', 'none')){
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow"); 

        }

        if ($(this).text("BLOG") && $("#askpage").css('display', 'none'))  {
            $(this).text("HOME");
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#tumblrcontent").offset().top}, "slow");

        }

        });
```

Comment: `if ($(this).text("HOME"))` always produces `TRUE` because it does not check if the text is `HOME`, it makes the text `HOME` so i guess you need to use `if ($(this).text() == "HOME")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $("#homebutton").click(function() { 

                    if ($(this).text =="HOME" && $("#tumblrcontent").is('display', 'none')){

                    }
}
```

[Check here](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Comment: This worked brilliantly, and so simple. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a tough time figuring out what it is you're trying to do. Let's examine your code and I'll tell you what your code does...

```
        if($(document.body).scrollTop() >= matchHeight) {
```

This above statement says "if the document body's scrollTop position is greater than or equal to the match height variable, do what's inside the next set of brackets, up to the else block."

```
            // this is where you're css amendments would be done
            if (targetDiv.text('BLOG')) {  targetDiv.text('HOME'); }
```

This line says "Set the targetDiv's text value to the string 'BLOG' and then evaluate the return value of the text function. If that's truthy, then set the text property of the targetDiv to the string 'HOME.'"

I highly doubt that's what you meant to do, as that makes no sense. This is probably where your problem lies. A couple of lines later, I see the same issue:

```
            if (targetDiv.text('HOME')) { targetDiv.text('BLOG'); }
```

You're *setting* the value of the target div's text value. You are not *evaluating* it. To evaluate the value, say this instead:

```
            if (targetDiv.text() === 'HOME') { targetDiv.text('BLOG'); }
```

That line says "If the text value of the targetDiv is "HOME," then set the targetDiv's text value to "BLOG."

Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: The section of the code you're referring to is used to change the text based on a user's own scrolling. The #homebutton.click function is meant to check what the text is (as it will indicate the users position on the page) and then jump to the other part of a page. What I am trying to accomplish is a jump between a home section and a blog section on the same page - and use one menu button to do this - which changes name and function depending on whether the user is in the blog section or the home section